# Using if-else in javascript to check datatable result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of script in .js file:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length - 1; i++) {
    var result = obj[i].end_time;
    if (result == null) {
        var displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '';
    }
    else {
        var displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '<b>Time: ' + '3/11/2014 6:00PM</b>';
    }
}
```

it loops 8 times. What I'm trying to do here is if I even get one `null` result based on loop, I want to display `displayProcessExpectedTotaltime` as space. otherwise, if all has value means result is not `null` then i want to display `Time`.

But everytime it takes the last `for-loop` value. So how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the loop when you get null after setting `displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = ''`, also use the `<` condition instead of `<=`

```
var displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '';
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      var result = obj[i].end_time;
      if (result == null) {
          displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '';
          break;

      } else {
          displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '<b>Time: ' + '3/11/2014 6:00PM</b>';

      }
}
```

**Edit** based on comments, using counter variable instead of breaking loop

```
var displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '';
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      var result = obj[i].end_time;
      if (result == null) {
          displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '';
          counter++;

      } else {
          displayProcessExpectedTotaltime = '<b>Time: ' + '3/11/2014 6:00PM</b>';

      }
}

if(counter > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: OK.Thats a good way . But in this case for loop still can continue its work , right ?

Comment: The loop will exit on getting the first empty string, as you need to show empty string where one of value is empty string

Comment: Yeah but , for-loop it self still has some process to do . But what i m trying to do is . I want to checked whether returned result has null or not , but this part only if-else .It is just to get displayProcessExpectedTotaltime   value and display it in somewhere in the page

Comment: You can use some variable and increment it in the if part instead of break, after the loop is finished you can get the value of that variable to find how many time you had null in result